# URL generator in python

Tags: python, url, web-crawler, generator

I've got an url which got the following pattern:

```
http://www.xf.com/position/?number=1&From=top&To=bottom
```

I want to generate a crawl listing given a list of position

```
positionToCrawl = [top, bottom, left, center, right]
```

I will iterate over that list but what I want to do is create an url, like:

```
http://www.xf.com/position/?number=1&From=X&To=Y
```

And to be able to replace X and Y with the element of my list, like

```
URLToReplace = http://www.xf.com/position/?number=1&From=X&To=Y
URLToCrawl = replaceElementXY(URLToReplace, "left", "right")
print URLToCrawl // Display: http://www.xf.com/position/?number=1&From=left&To=right
```

If you guys know a library that do something like that would be great other way, I guess I will have to implement it, but I'm sure this has already been implemented, but I didn't find it.

Comment: Have you tried anything? There are a lot of ways you could do this.

Comment: I can do it by implementing a function but I would greatly prefer using a librayry

Comment: What's wrong with `.format()`?

Comment: Make an answer I validate it, i will use .format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use `.format()` for this:

```
'http://www.xf.com/position/?number=1&From={0}&To={1}'.format('left', 'right')
```